# SQL-запрос с условием "Если нету"

Tags: sql

Есть таблица `t` с полями `id`, `a` и `b`.
 Как сделать такой запрос "Выбрать все записи из t где a>0 , если таких нет то такие где b>0". 
И вообще возможно ли это? Сейчас приходится делать 2 запроса, а хотелось бы одним обойтись.

Comment: оператор IF есть в Stored Procedure. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/

Comment: @argamidon, спасибо, буду смотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from t where a>0
or (not exists(select 1 from t where a>0) and b>0)
```

[EXISTS](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_exists_predicate.html)